# Получить значения из Collections<?> и сохранить их в List

Tags: java, list, коллекции, foreach

циклом forEach беру value из Collections и добавляю их в List

вот вырезка из моего кода:

```
List<String> rolesList = new ArrayList<>();
List<? extends GrantedAuthority> collect = 
   currentUser.getAuthorities().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
for (GrantedAuthority colList: collect) {
  rolesList.add(colList.getAuthority());
}
```

Можно ли как-то это сделать без forEach.

Comment: stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: @GenCloud, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList());